# Passing type to subroutine in another module

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I have a little problem i cant find the solution to, but i'm sure there is one. 
I define a type in a module, and want to use that type as an argument to a constructor in another module. Something like this:
First File:

```
module Simulation_mod
    use SolverParameters_mod
    type, public :: Simulation_class
        type(SolverParameters_class), public :: SolverParameters
    end type
    type(Simulation_class), public :: Simulation
end module
```

Second file:

```
module SolverParameters_mod
    implicit none
    type, public :: SolverParameters_class
        private
        real :: MaxRelError
        integer :: MaxNumberIter
        integer :: NumericalDamping
        real, dimension(:), allocatable :: InitialValue
    end type SolverParameters_class
end module
```

Third file:

```
module Solver_mod
use Simulation_mod
type, public :: Solver_class
    private
    real :: MaxRelError
    integer :: MaxNumberIter
    integer :: NumericalDamping
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: InitialValue
end type Solver_class

interface Solver_class
module procedure InitSolver
end interface Solver_class

contains

subroutine InitSolver(VarSolverParameters)
    ! Declaring part
    type(Solver_class) :: Solver
    class(SolverParameters), intent(in) :: VarSolverParameters
    ! Executing part
    Solver%MaxRelError = VarSolverParameters%GetMaxRelError
    Solver%MaxNumberIter = VarSolverParameters%GetMaxNumberIter
    Solver%NumericalDamping = VarSolverParameters%GetNumericalDamping
    Solver%InitialValue = VarSolverParameters%GetInitialValue
end subroutine InitSolver
end module Solver_mod
```

The Getter functions are defined properly. When trying to compile, i get `error #6457: This derived type name has not been declared.   [SOLVERPARAMETERS]
        class(SolverParameters), intent(in) :: VarSolverParameters
--------------^`

How do i achieve to pass the object `SolverParameters` to the constructor `InitSolver` of type `Solver_class`?

Comment: `type(SolverParameters_class), public :: SolverParameters` in the first code snippet. But i think i see the problem. Is there something like a generic type?

Comment: `SolverParameters` is a variable of type `SolverParameters_class`, there.  You need to use the type in the `class` declaration, not a variable, as you do with `type(Solver_class) :: Solver`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I somehow knew it was a dumb mistake